# Enumerations and bitwise operators with Registers

Tags: c, embedded

We are all used to this kind of manipulating registers:

```
SomeRegister |= (1 << What_ever_bit_I_wanna_change ) // we do this for changing a specific bit to one without changing the others.

SomeRegister &= ~(1 << What_ever_bit_I_wanna_change ) // we do this for changing a specific bit to zero without changing the others.
```

I am planning to use the same paradigm, but with enumerations, something like this:

```
typedef enum  {
Acc_2g  (Something to change only the desired bits in the related register that I don't know how to do),
Acc_4g (Something to change only the desired bits in the related register that I don't know how to do)
}Res;
```

Any idea how to use the bitwise operators inside the enumeration?

Comment: You can assign values to enumeration symbols, e.g. `enum {x=(1<<3), y=(1<<4), ...}` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You do know that you can initialize an enumeration value to any integer? Like e.g. `Acc_2g = 4`? You can use any compile-time constant expression for the initialization, like e.g. `Acc_2g = 1 << 2`. [A good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum is merely a set of integer constants, they cannot cause actions on data at run-time. So for example while you can define:

```
typedef enum  
{
    Acc_2g = 1 << 2,
    Acc_4g = 1 << 4
} Res ;
```

This does not "change" any bits as requested in the question.  You still have to use the same idiom:

```
SomeRegister |= Acc_2g ;
SomeRegister &= ~(Acc_4g) ;
```

What you probably need is a struct with bit-fields.  Note however that if the intent is to access specific bits in some hardware register, you will need to consult your compiler's documentation on how it it packs bit-fields with respect to bit order and padding - such things are implementation/target dependent, but this need not necessarily be avoided when the the register is also target specific.

For example, for some hypothetical 8 bit register:

```
typedef union
{
    uint8_t byte;

    struct
    {
         uint8_t bit012 : 3;
         uint8_t bit34  : 2;
         uint8_t bit5   : 1;
         uint8_t bit6   : 1;
         uint8_t bit7   : 1;
    } bits ;

} registerType;
```

Then this type can be used to create a pointer to the register:

```
registerType *pReg = (registerType*)0x00008000;
```

The the register may be accessed as bit-fields:

```
pReg->bits.bit5 = 1;
pReg->bits.bit012 = 7;
```

Or as an entire register:

```
pReg->byte = 0x55;
```

One can go further by defining a structure for all registers of a single peripheral for example.

Comment: And in C11, you could use an anonymous inner struct (drop `bits` from the definition), and then you could use `pReg->bit5 = 0;`, for example.  Also note that the standard does not specify whether `bit012` will be at the most significant or least significant end of the storage unit that holds it.

Comment: @chux :  I think I did: *"consult your compiler's documentation on how it it packs bit-fields with respect to bit order and padding"*.